# Asymmertic key encryption not working

Tags: java, security

Below mentioned is a code which is showing exception while running. Wanted to understand the public key / private key working.

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

        Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        aes.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,publicKey);
        byte[] cipherText = aes.doFinal("my password".getBytes());
        System.out.println(new String(cipherText));
```

Below mentioned is exception.

**Exception in thread "main" java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size or default parameters**

Comment: You instantiate RSA key generator while you use AES encryption.

Comment: Not sure about that implementation, but AES is a symmetric cipher. Here you might find more information on how to pick an asymmatric one. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

Comment: Thank You Very Much. I have changed the AES to RSA by changing the line to RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding for cipher.getInstance and it worked fine for me.